# AWS API Gateway accept Content-type: application/xml

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've got a question about AWS API Gateway..

I want to process an other companies API into my own dynamoDB in AWS.
They can only POST an XML formatted to my API.
My setup is API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB.

But how can do set up a API Gateway POST in such a way that i accepts the XML posted by them?

Link to their XML Post setup (it's just the uplink data): 
http://zakelijke-community.kpn.com/t5/Data/Application-data-API/ta-p/4768

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a request mapping template for "application/xml" which will be triggered when the client sends a "Content-Type" header of "application/xml".

While API Gateway doesn't yet offer first-class support for XML, you can simply send the XML payload to Lambda in a JSON string field:

```
{ 
   "bodyXml" : "$input.body"
}
```

In your Lambda function, you can use your XML parsing library of choice to process the XML.

Hope this helps,
Ryan