# AWS API Gateway accept XML request

Tags: json, xml, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've followed the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164698/aws-api-gateway-accept-content-type-application-xml%20here) and [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=650072) where in the `Integration Request` section I have a mapping for `application/json` to wrap the XML into a JSON object. This all works fine in the API Gateway test console. I put `Content-Type application/xml` for my headers and the request goes in and gets transformed to JSON. However, when I test it from Postman I have to put in `application/json` for the request to work. Otherwise when I put in `application/xml` I receive an error.

Is this the correct way to allow XML requests? I've tried setting `application/xml` in `Integration Request` but I just end up getting `Unsupported media type` error.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect the client to send XML (and thus Content-Type: application/xml) in the request, you would define your request mapping template as "application/xml".

Note that the client **must** send Content-Type: application/xml. If the client sends a different content type the request would fail with 415 (this behavior is configurable).

Test invoke in the console assumes the Content-Type as "application/json" so you may see different behavior than from Postman.

Hope this helps,
Ryan

Comment: Do you mean that the test invoke in the console is buggy? Because i explicitly set Content-Type : application/xml and it still asumes json

Answer (score -1):

Non-JSON data is *not supported* by Lambda. See this discussion thread for more information: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221346